# How can I add image file in SQLite database using Flask, Python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm writing a small web-shop using Python and web-framework Flask.

I'm trying to add image file in SQLite database using this

```
@app.route('/new_product_reg', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def new_product_reg():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        img_name = request.form['product_img']
        product_img = readImage(img_name)
        product_img_binary = lite.Binary(product_img)

        product_data = NewProduct(product_img=product_img_binary)

        try:
            db.session.add(product_data)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/new_product_reg')
        except:
            return "ERROR!"
```

Where `readImage` is

```
def readImage(img_name):
   try:
       fin = open(img_name, 'rb')
       img = fin.read()
       return img
   except:
       print("ERROR!!")
```

Form where I taked the image:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="file" name=product_img id="product_img"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </from>
```

And the class of database where I want to add image looks like that:

```
class NewProduct(db.Model):
    product_img = db.Column(db.BLOB())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<NewProduct %r>' % self.id
```

So, the problem is, when I added image by pressing "Add Image" button in form and pressed "Submit" button I get the BadRequestKeyError 400. The debugger said that the problem is in `img_name = request.form['product_img']`. So how can I fix that and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I want to say that storing large and medium pictures directly in SQLite is not a very good solution. Learn more here: https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html

For your problem, try to do as in the documentation:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Note there is used:

```
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
```

And perhaps this article will also help you:
[Python SQLite BLOB to Insert and Retrieve file and images](https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-blob-insert-and-retrieve-digital-data/)

Comment: I tried to do how you said and i get "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage" in line "with open(img_name, 'rb') as file:"

Comment: After `file = request.files['file']`, in `file` you have object type FileStorage.
Read about FileStorage here: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save

It says how to get a file object from it.

Comment: So what should I do with FileStorage to make it binary and write to db?

Comment: Didn't helped, with file.stream.read() get same error  - "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223582/discussion-between-yuriy-krasilnikov-and-h4cktivist).